Enable disable multiple inputs on dropdown change selection
I am trying to enable or disable multiple text boxes on selection box change.  Meaning when I select any option in a selection box, all fields should be enabled.
Tried the JavaScript and Html below but It only works with the option value of 8 when selected in the dropdown list.  However I would like it to work with any option selected.  It should enable the first 14 textbox fields with any option selected in the dropdown list and the second dropdown list should enable / disable the last 14 texboxes.


function EnableDisableTextBox(ALE2) {
  var selectedValue = ALE1.options[ALE1.selectedIndex].value;
  var ALE2 = document.getElementById("ALE2");
  ALE2.disabled = selectedValue == 8 ? false : true;
  if (!ALE2.disabled) {
    ALE2.focus();
  }
}
<table class="table table-bordered no-margin">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    S
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <select id="ALE1" name="ALE1" class="form-control" onchange="EnableDisableTextBox(this)" required="True">
            <option value="">
              ----
            </option>
            <cfloop query="qryGetALESelect">
              <option value="#ale1#">
                #ALE1#
              </option>
            </cfloop>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE2" name="ALE2" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <select id="ALE3" name="ALE3" class="form-control" required="True">
            <option value="">
              ----
            </option>
            <cfloop query="qryGetALESelect">
              <option value="ALE1">
                #ALE1#
              </option>
            </cfloop>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE4" name="ALE4" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    T
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE5" name="ALE5" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE6" name="ALE6" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    A
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE8" name="ALE8" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE9" name="ALE9" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE10" name="ALE10" value="" pattern="^[ 
                    A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled" </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE11" name="ALE11" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    R
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE12" name="ALE12" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE13" name="ALE13" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    B
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE14" name="ALE14" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE15" name="ALE15" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE16" name="ALE16" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE17" name="ALE17" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    O
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE18" name="ALE18" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE19" name="ALE19" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    A
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE20" name="ALE20" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE21" name="ALE21" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE22" name="ALE22" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE23" name="ALE23" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    R
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE24" name="ALE24" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE25" name="ALE25" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
                    D
                </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE26" name="ALE26" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE27" name="ALE27" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE28" name="ALE28" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE29" name="ALE29" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE30" name="ALE30" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE31" name="ALE31" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




ALE1 is undefined. Did you mean to use: function EnableDisableTextBox(ALE1) { ? Also, where in your code do you iterate all the text fields?

Also, no need to use = selectedValue == 8 ? false : true just use = selectedValue === "8";

I do not want to use the value 8  for all the values.  It should be any value.  Im not really that good with javascript, just coldfusion.  The function works to enable one textbox.  I would like it to enable the first 14 text boxes when selecting any option.

@In such case invert the logic. Check for: const noValue = elALE1.value === ""; like in the answer below


Don't use inline JS like onchange. JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file. Query your selector and use .addEventListener() instead.
Use the data-* attribute like data-toggle-cols="2,3" on your select elements, where the value "2,3" indicates the nth columns to target in the table. Having those numbers you can easily construct a selector like td:nth-child(2) input[type="text"], td:nth-child(3) input[type="text"] to get all the needed inputs
Query those inputs using .querySelectorAll() and then .forEach() that NodeList and set the disabled Element property as desired.

Example:


// DOM utils

const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelectorAll(sel);


// Task

const toggleColumnsTextBox = (elSelect) => {
  let nth = elSelect.dataset.toggleCols; // get cols indexes string "2,3"
  nth = nth.replace(/ /g, "").split(","); // convert to array i.e: [2, 3]
  const selector = nth.map(n => `td:nth-child(${n}) input[type="text"]`).join(", "); // construct selector
  console.log(selector)
  const noValue = elSelect.value.trim() === ""; // Boolean (true if value is "" empty string)
  const elTable = elSelect.closest("table"); // Get the parent table
  const elsInputs = els(selector, elTable); // Get all input[type=text] of `nth` columns

  elsInputs.forEach((elInput) => {
    elInput.disabled = noValue;
  });
};

els("[data-toggle-cols]").forEach((elSelect) => {
  elSelect.addEventListener("input", () => {
    toggleColumnsTextBox(elSelect);
  });
});
<table class="table table-bordered no-margin">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>S</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <select data-toggle-cols="2,3" id="ALE1" name="ALE1" class="form-control" required="True">
            <option value="">----</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE2" name="ALE2" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <select data-toggle-cols="4,5" id="ALE3" name="ALE3" class="form-control" required="True">
            <option value="">----</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE4" name="ALE4" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>T</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE5" name="ALE5" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE6" name="ALE6" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>A</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE8" name="ALE8" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE9" name="ALE9" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE10" name="ALE10" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled" </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE11" name="ALE11" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>R</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE12" name="ALE12" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE13" name="ALE13" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>B</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE14" name="ALE14" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE15" name="ALE15" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE16" name="ALE16" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE17" name="ALE17" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>O</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE18" name="ALE18" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE19" name="ALE19" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>A</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE20" name="ALE20" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE21" name="ALE21" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE22" name="ALE22" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE23" name="ALE23" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>R</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE24" name="ALE24" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE25" name="ALE25" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>D</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE26" name="ALE26" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE27" name="ALE27" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE28" name="ALE28" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE29" name="ALE29" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE30" name="ALE30" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ALE31" name="ALE31" value="" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\[\]()*\-+/%]*$" maxlength="2" placeholder="" data-error="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Why not elALE1.addEventListener("input", enableDisableTextBox);

The second dropdown should enable / disable the  third and fourth column of text boxes.

@GaryRobinson edited my answer to reflect the missing requirement.

I may be doing something wrong because clearly it works when you run the snippet code, but when I plug it into my html for the site -  its not working.

@GaryRobinson have you added: data-toggle-cols="4,5" attribute to your <select> ?
